# SWF есть ли способ управлять swf player

Tags: javascript, html, css, swf

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="myFlashContent">
    <param name="movie" value="swf/video.swf">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swf/video.swf" width="800" height="600">
    <!--<![endif]-->
     <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
      <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
     </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
   </object>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

что бы player был с панелью управления - как это реализовать ?

Comment: Что за панель управления и какое управление над swf требуется? Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате, и т. д.

Comment: кнопки - play pause next prew - это называется панель управления

Comment: ну и естественно громкость | на весь экран  и т д

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможна установка связей между исполняемым кодом внутри объекта SWF и Javascript. Для этого необходимо использовать [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Важно уточнить, что вызывать можно будет только те методы, которые были явно указаны при создании (программировании) Flash, т.е. программист оставил возможность управлять или следить за исполнением Flash из окружения (например из браузера используя JavaScript).

Также стоит добавить про предопределенные функции для javascript, которые могут контролировать процесс запуска анимации для flash.

Это `Play()`, `StopPlay()`, `GotoFrame(n)`, где `n` - это номер кадра.

Comment: Возможно ли растянуть на весь экран?

Comment: @LenovoID Высота и ширина объекта меняются также как и для любого другого элемента HTML, а вот поведение flash при изменении размера контейнера определяются при компиляции SWF. Существуют четыре константы [StageScaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html) - EXACT_FIT, NO_BORDER, NO_SCALE, SHOW_ALL. Таким образом вы можете изменять размеры тэга объект свободно, но вот поведение самого Flash при этих действиях определять из окружения сможете только если оставили функцию обратного вызова описанную в ответе выше.